# Should a utility class be static?

Tags: java

If I have to design a Utility class( such as ByteUtils or StreamUtils or StringUtils), what is the best design choice for them.

- Should they be static classes (as I won't have any states to store)
- Should they be non-static classes ( so that if the objects are not used, they will be gc'd)

PS: By static class, I meant a class with static methods(and not the inner static class)

Please give advice on design choices for this ?

Comment: You need to reword this question. Outer level classes cannot be static in Java. They can have nothing but static *methods.* Not the same thing.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. I meant a class with methods being static

Comment: While your examples (Byte, String, Stream) should be fairly small,  if you happen to have a 1k LOC in EJB that uses a mapper utility that has static methods, testing of that EJB becomes quite difficult.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If it is a general purpose utility, static is IMO better. You stated that you will not have any states to store, so I don't see why should you make it non-static. Declaring it to be static will save memory too.

Comment: A screw driver doesn't change, it always do the same thing. If the same can be said for your utility class, definitely make it static.

Comment: This hold true for all methods that do not rely on the state of the object. Not just utility class methods.

Comment: Quite sure making utility class static won't save you enough memory to do something remarkable. So not the true reason, I'd say

Answer (score 81):

My utility classes look like this:

```
// final, because it's not supposed to be subclassed
public final class FooUtil {

    // private constructor to avoid unnecessary instantiation of the class
    private FooUtil() {
    }

    public static int doSomethingUseful() {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that, although this makes the utility methods easily testable, and easily accessible from the outside, it also makes the classes using them hard to unit-test, because it's not easy to mock these utility methods. Having too many of such utility classes can be a sign of a lack of OO design (procedural programming), and can really make the code hard to test.

If you're using a dependency injection framework (Spring, Guice, whatever), it might be a good idea to just make the utility class instantiatable, with non-static methods, and make it an injectable singleton. This way, classes using these utility methods can be tested by mocking the utility object.

Comment: We can unit test static methods using powermock http://code.google.com/p/powermock/

Comment: @nibin012 just because you can, doesn't mean you should. In my project PowerMock is a tool of constant sorrow - it's bad with other tools as it messes with class loaders too much.

Comment: @jb-nizet could you please provide a minimal example of: 
> it might be a good idea to just make the utility class instantiatable, with non-static methods, and make it an injectable singleton.
It SGTM but I struggle to implement.

Comment: "If you're using a dependency injection framework" - and if not, then it's a bad idea?

Comment: you are not unit testing just becauase you use powermocks. In general using a mock like powermock to test a static method you design is probably wrong in some way, as you are overwriting "stateless" methods.

Comment: I don't agree with the final paragraph, having dependency injection or even having constructor based dependencies doesn't automatically make a utility class eligible/recommendable to being instantiable. A **pure** (aka has no side effects) function that always return same value for the same given input, should definitely be static, and it's not a bad thing for Classes testability, because the function itself is unit tested. Why an `f(x,y)=x+y` should ever be injected to a class as a dependency ? it's a constant response.....TBC

Comment: Some argue what if we wanted to test a different implementation of static methods, then I'd say this is actually a "state" case here, and it should be done either through a configurable state that is written as a switch which calls static methods implementations if they're all known, or those static methods can simply be called from inside a wrapper implementation of the contract interface API, which would be normally injected through DI framework or constructors.  **A switch of implementation is a "statefulness" case, disregarding this would cause people to think static utils are bad**

Answer (score 24):

Just because something can be static, doesn't mean it should be static.

There is another consideration to all this: mocking. It's harder to mock static methods in your tests than it is to mock the behaviour of an instance of a class.

Talk of unnecessary heap allocations and GCing of objects smacks of premature optimisation to me. The JVM will do a pretty good job at optimising away this sort of issue.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to define a Utility class is as an enum with no instances

```
public enum Utility {;
     public static int utilityMethod(int x) { /* ... */ }
}
```

A utility class shouldn't have any state or have minimal state so you shouldn't worrying about GCs.

You can have other stateful classes for specific purposes like Builder, Factory, you can create the object as desired and discard it when you have finished.

Comment: I assume you don't mean a static nested class. This avoids needing to remember to create the private constructor to prevent people accidentally creating an instance of the utility class. Enums are `final` by default.

Comment: This is indeed a new idea for me. Thanks for this tip! But the general purpose of enum's are to store constants and have operations that support those constants. I guess it is also a tiny misuse of enum as we all understand.

Comment: In Java, `enum` can have mutable fields, implement interfaces and abstract methods so they are much more than just constants. ;)

Comment: This is the recommended way by effective java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, while this is true, it smacks of over engineering to me. Since 1996, I can count a sum total of zero times that I've seen someone accidentally instantiate a class meant to be a simple static utility. Providing such protections is silly IMO, because the consequences of instantiating something like this is you notice immediately that it won't work. Putting in an `enum` into the mix however changes how the tired engineer at 3am hopped on caffeine will read the thing and make him wonder for a moment what's going on.  It's just not a common idiom. Use `class` and be happy.

Comment: @tgm1024 I have seen developer create instances with a private constructor. I don't see how using a `class` makes it easier to see that a class has no instances. In Java 8 we will probably use static methods on interfaces more and utility classes less.

Comment: The *primary* point I'm truly making here is that when you use an `enum`, you are telegraphing to the reader that there is a reason for enumeration hidden in its design.  There isn't.  You're only trying to make it easier than putting in a `final` and private constructor, neither of which are an issue IMO.  That's an unusual idiom.  And you saw someone trying to instantiate a class of utility static methods?  Does this matter?  If someone sees the class as supplying the methods they need, they know what they are----*why* would they instantiate it? And what happens if they did?  Not much.

Comment: I think we have been needing to question some of our over-protective thinking for quite some time now.  Freaking out over gotos, avoiding multiple returns, instantiation protection, etc., etc., there is really very limited up side to all of this.  However what ***is*** worth protecting is the readability of the code.  Always try to remain as close to the no-brainer category as you can.

Comment: @tgm1024 my primary point is that to check you have a utility class you need to check there are no instances. To do this for a class means reading the whole class for constructors or with `enum` you have to read the first line after the declaration. Only `enum` allows you to elegantly say this whereas for a class this has to be inferred from reading all the code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I don't see that as true.  You don't first check to see if you have a utility class or not by looking through the source, you typically look for the functionality you need.  If the documentation shows that it exists as a static, you then decide to call it.  If you mean that an engineer needs to do extra work to make sure that no one is instantiating the thing, I'm still not seeing it as an issue.  You have a class.  You have functionality.  You use it.  Everything else is gold-plating the tire-irons IMO.  Anyway, we're going in circles; to each his own.

Comment: One of the problems with using Enum is that you cannot have a static method called `valueOf` in your utility class. Not a major issue though.

Comment: @AdamGent agree, more generally there is some name space pollution as a result of this approach.  It is as simple as you can get though.

Answer (score 6):

Its good to make the class as non-static with a private constructor:

- if we make the class static then class will be loaded when the application is deployed, if it is non-static then the class will be loaded when there is a call to one of its static methods
- creating a private constructor will avoid instantiating the class

Comment: Then how to use this class? NonStatic with private constrctr

Answer (score 4):

Usually utility classes contain static methods and no attributes, this approach makes it easier to use their methods without instantiating the class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you can make them static, then definitely do so!

In other words, if they don't have state, they should be static.

Comment: I've coded in projects that followed that principle. "If you can", that is. Testing was nightmarish thanks to that. And PowerMock made matters worse, due to it's classloader magic that collided with other tools in never-easy-to-figure-out ways. Downvoted.

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami, I agree in general with the "if you can".  However, I think what Petar was saying was "if there's no reason to use anything other than static then use static" (or less clumsy words to that effect).  At least that's the meaning I took from his statement.  IOW, "If you don't *need* an instance, then don't *make* an instance just to have one."  Again, my take on his statement.

Comment: it helps with refactoring and readability to know that a method does not mutate the state of objects of that class

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have no state to store then there is nothing to GC, so I would go with static, that way you avoid any unnecessary heap allocations and GC.

Answer (score 2):

Pure utility classes should usually be static. When you have a class with well-defined input and output, no side effects and no state, then by definition it should be a static class.

In general, don't add complexity (dependency injection in this case) before it's necessary and there's a benefit in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody here mention that static utility methods are not extensible. You cannot override them. You cannot take advantage of OOP (particularly polymorphysm, which is most powerful feature of OOP). That leads to code duplication.

P.S. I found this article very helpful. http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

Comment: Define "extensible"... there's nothing preventing you from making overloads in your _own_ tool classes that call the existing tools (not a big difference from subclassing/overloading IMO), and if you want to prevent code duplication, you can always use generics to allow a wider range of types to be handled by your tool function.

Comment: That article seems to go for a "use objects for the sake of it being OOP" mindset, which IMO is just _memory pollution_. Not only does it give extra work to the GC, but since object references can be stored, all object creation holds a risk of creating memory leaks. Not worth it.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted.  A good article that summarizes why this is the better option: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/avoid-utility-classes/

Comment: @Nyerguds you're absolutely wrong about extra work for the GC.  The usual way to do this is to have a singleton (a static getInstance() method) with a private constructor.

Comment: @Pratik Then it's memory pollution, since it keeps those objects indefinitely.

Comment: I'm not saying that utility classes shouldn't be static. You have to be sure that your static method is used only as utility and have no business logic in it.
By extensible I mean it is "flexible enough to change", i had experience with code that used lots of static methods without any proper abstractions, end up with lots of duplication.

Comment: @Nyerguds Just consider the trade-off.  The benefits you get are overwhelming compared to the few bytes it will take in memory.  It's a no-brainer.

Comment: @Pratik What benefits? I don't see any benefits at all tbh.

Comment: @Nyerguds I'll link to the article again that explains the benefits: vojtechruzicka.com/avoid-utility-classes

Comment: Utility classes usually deal with specific types that are not user classes. For example, I have an `ImageUtils` class in c# dealing with manipulation of `System.Bitmap` objects, and with manipulating byte arrays that function as images, and can convert to/from `Bitmap` objects. I cannot extend `System.Bitmap` and include these tools inside it, and `Byte` class itself is unrelated to images. Therefore a utility class is the only logical solution.